# How can I set custom dark colors for the SwipeRefreshLayout icon

Tags: android

I want to customize the refresh icon so that the circular background is black and the animated ring is blue.

I tried calling:

```java
pullRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.background));
```

but it didn't seem to affect the refresh icon at all. Am I using this incorrectly, or is there some other way to set custom colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setColorSchemeColors` specifies the color of the ring, not the background. To color the ring blue, call:

```java
pullRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
```

or more concisely:

```java
pullRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.blue);
```

To set the background color of the icon, call

```java
pullRefreshLayout.setProgressBackgroundColorSchemeResource(R.color.background);
```

Docs:

- [`setColorSchemeColors`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/swiperefreshlayout/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout#setColorSchemeColors(int...))
- [`setColorSchemeResources`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/swiperefreshlayout/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout#setColorSchemeResources(int...))
- [`setProgressBackgroundColorSchemeResource`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/swiperefreshlayout/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout#setProgressBackgroundColorSchemeResource(int))